# Sort nested JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an **array of objects** as below. I want to **recursively sort** this based on the key values

```
{
      "settingsList": [
        {
          "category1": [
            {
              "categoryName": "DRIVER",
              "description": "DRIVER",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "BALL",
              "description": "BALL",
              "sequence": 2
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "SAMPLE",
              "description": "SAMPLE",
              "sequence": 3
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "USER",
              "description": "USER",
              "sequence": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category2": [
            {
              "paramName": "CPP",
              "description": "CPP",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "paramName": "PP",
              "description": "PP",
              "sequence": 2
            },
            {
              "paramName": "MP",
              "description": "MP",
              "sequence": 3
            }
          ]
        }
        {
          "source": {
            "instanceName": "instance_1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I efficiently sort recursively to display it sorted alphabetically on the key values.
**Expected output:**

```
{
      "settingsList": [
        {
          "category": [
            {
              "categoryName": "BALL",
              "description": "BALL",
              "sequence": 2
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "DRIVER",
              "description": "DRIVER",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "SAMPLE",
              "description": "SAMPLE",
              "sequence": 3
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "USER",
              "description": "USER",
              "sequence": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category2": [
            {
              "paramName": "CPP",
              "description": "CPP",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "paramName": "MP",
              "description": "MP",
              "sequence": 3
            },
            {
              "paramName": "PP",
              "description": "PP",
              "sequence": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": {
            "instanceName": "instance_1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

below is the sample code that was tried

```js
var object = {
      "settingsList": [
        {
          "category1": [
            {
              "categoryName": "DRIVER",
              "description": "DRIVER",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "BALL",
              "description": "BALL",
              "sequence": 2
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "SAMPLE",
              "description": "SAMPLE",
              "sequence": 3
            },
            {
              "categoryName": "USER",
              "description": "USER",
              "sequence": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category2": [
            {
              "paramName": "CPP",
              "description": "CPP",
              "sequence": 1
            },
            {
              "paramName": "PP",
              "description": "PP",
              "sequence": 2
            },
            {
              "paramName": "MP",
              "description": "MP",
              "sequence": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": {
            "instanceName": "instance_1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }

var keys = Object.keys(object);

var sortedKeys = keys.sort((key1, key2)=>{
    key1 = key1.toLowerCase();
    key2 = key2.toLowerCase();
    if(key1 < key2) return -1;
    if(key1 > key2) return 1;
    return 0;
})

 function sortData(object){
    var newObject = {},
        keys = Object.keys(object);
        
   keys.sort(function(key1, key2){
        key1 = key1.toLowerCase();
        key2 = key2.toLowerCase();
        if(key1 < key2) return -1;
        if(key1 > key2) return 1;
        return 0;
    });


  for(var index in keys){
        var key = keys[index];
        if(typeof object[key] == 'object' && !(object[key] instanceof Array)){
            newObject[key] = sortData(object[key]);
        } else {
            newObject[key] = object[key];
        }
    }

    return newObject;
}

var sortedData=sortData(object)

console.log(sortedData)
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You should add the code you've already attempted to your question.

Comment: So, you wish to sort all the category arrays based on `description`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: not on desc, but on the categoryName for category1, paramName for category2 and so on

Comment: I've you find the solution ? Is my answer helped you ?

Comment: this one is sorting by the keys only.. i want to sort by values of the keys.. I m trying to modify it to accomodate

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to achieved is called deep sort.

You can use [deep-sort-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-sort-object) library as follow :

```
var sortobject = require('deep-sort-object');
var sortedData = sortobject(object);
console.log(sortedData);
```

Or if you don't want to use a library, you can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ninapavlich/1697bcc107052f5b884a794d307845fe) as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = { settingsList: [{ category1: [{ categoryName: 'DRIVER', description: 'DRIVER', sequence: 1 }, { categoryName: 'BALL', description: 'BALL', sequence: 2 }, { categoryName: 'SAMPLE', description: 'SAMPLE', sequence: 3 }, { categoryName: 'USER', description: 'USER', sequence: 4 }] }, { category2: [{ paramName: 'CPP', description: 'CPP', sequence: 1 }, { paramName: 'PP', description: 'PP', sequence: 2 }, { paramName: 'MP', description: 'MP', sequence: 3 }] }, { source: { instanceName: 'instance_1' } }] };

const sort = (data) => {
  const logic = {
    'settingsList[*].category1': (value) => value.sort((a, b) => a.categoryName.localeCompare(b.categoryName)),
    'settingsList[*].category2': (value) => value.sort((a, b) => a.paramName.localeCompare(b.paramName))
  };

  objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
    filterFn: ({ value, matchedBy }) => {
      matchedBy.forEach((needle) => logic[needle](value));
    }
  })(data);
};

console.log(sort(myData));
// => undefined

console.log(myData);
// => { settingsList: [ { category1: [ { categoryName: 'BALL', description: 'BALL', sequence: 2 }, { categoryName: 'DRIVER', description: 'DRIVER', sequence: 1 }, { categoryName: 'SAMPLE', description: 'SAMPLE', sequence: 3 }, { categoryName: 'USER', description: 'USER', sequence: 4 } ] }, { category2: [ { paramName: 'CPP', description: 'CPP', sequence: 1 }, { paramName: 'MP', description: 'MP', sequence: 3 }, { paramName: 'PP', description: 'PP', sequence: 2 } ] }, { source: { instanceName: 'instance_1' } } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.4.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)